# Render to Texture Inversed

Tags: c++, rendering, directx-11, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render to texture, but the texture is stenciling out the opposite to what I want it to do. i.e. The clear colour is saved out and rendered, while the actual object I want to render is alpha'd out.

```
//Set the render target
RenderToTexture(RENDERTEXTURE_PARTICLESTAGE);
//Draw the scene (using the new render target)
m_Renderer.Draw();
//Save the file out so we can see the result
m_pRenderTextures[RENDERTEXTURE_PARTICLESTAGE]->SaveToFile(L"data/particle.tga");
This is the code I use to render to texture
```

In the render to texture function, I do this

```
m_pDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_pRenderTargetView, _pDepthStencilView);
```

**m_pRenderTargetView** being independent to the m_pRenderTexture object, **_pDepthStencilView** being passed in from my main application.

*I also clear the render target and clear the depth stencil beforehand, I just left the code out to keep the question bloating to minimum.*

I'm sure this isn't just a problem saving out the texture - I tried to render the resource directly back into the application and got the same result.

I'm fairly sure it is because of my Depth Stencil Description, but I'm not sure exactly what could be wrong.

```
//Depth Stencil
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC DepthStencilDescription;
    {
        DepthStencilDescription.Width               = m_uiClientWidth;
        DepthStencilDescription.Height              = m_uiClientHeight;
        DepthStencilDescription.MipLevels           = 1;
        DepthStencilDescription.ArraySize           = 1;
        DepthStencilDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
        DepthStencilDescription.SampleDesc.Count    = 1;
        DepthStencilDescription.SampleDesc.Quality  = 0;
        DepthStencilDescription.Usage               = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        DepthStencilDescription.BindFlags           = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
        DepthStencilDescription.CPUAccessFlags      = 0; 
        DepthStencilDescription.MiscFlags           = 0;
    }
    Utility::Assert(m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&DepthStencilDescription, 0, &m_pDepthStencilBuffer));
    Utility::Assert(m_pDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(m_pDepthStencilBuffer, 0, &m_pDepthStencilView));
```

As opposed to my Texture Description in my RenderTextureClass which is

```
TextureDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
```

However trying to make them match each other threw an error.

Here is the PIX results of what is going on:

[image: This is me rendering to texture]
This is when I render to texture. It looks fine so far...
[image]
But I save the texture out and this is what it looks like
[image]
Rendering the texture back to the screen directly through the shader resource view... (Not a problem of the texture saving function)
The white colour is actually the BackBuffer's  clear colour, the red colour is the RenderTexture's clear colour. So it has saved out the opposite of what I want.

**I am expecting blue spheres on a white background**

**If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great. Cheers :)**

Comment: Do you have a picture of the problem?

Comment: It seems like something with either your blend state or depth/stencil state sent to the output merger stage. What states are you setting before the final Draw call?

Comment: I call:
OMSetRenderTargets,
ClearRenderTargetView, and
ClearDepthStencilView between the draw calls.
I call these functions when swapping out the RenderTargetView. I call it between each draw call and literally the only difference between them is I am using a m_pRenderTargetView which belongs to each object

Comment: You haven't enabled alpha blending anywhere?

Comment: Can you post the initialization code for your blend state and rasterizer state?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry it was the blend state that was causing the problem. I have no idea what I was doing wrong, but when I played with the blend states I managed to get it working :)